# Mouseup event is intermittant from Scaled KineticJS layer

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

See here for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tigz_uk/B8UDq/45/embedded/result/

Fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/tigz_uk/B8UDq/45/

Most Relevant snippet:

```
function whenAreaSelected(stage, layer, image) {
    var rect, down = false;
    var eventObj = layer;
    eventObj.off("mousedown");
    eventObj.off("mousemove");
    eventObj.off("mouseup");
    eventObj.on("mousedown", function (e) {
        console.log("Mousedown...");
        if (rect) {
            rect.remove();
        }            
        var relativePos = getRelativePos ( stage, layer);

        down = true;
        var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255),
            g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255),
            b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: relativePos.x,
            y: relativePos.y,
            width: 11,
            height: 1,
            fill: 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            opacity: 0.3
        });
        layer.add(rect);
    });

    eventObj.on("mousemove", function (e) {
        if (!down) return;
        var relativePos = getRelativePos ( stage, layer );
        var p = rect.attrs;

        rect.setWidth(relativePos.x - p.x);
        rect.setHeight(relativePos.y - p.y);
        layer.draw();
    });

    eventObj.on("mouseup", function (e) {
        console.log("Mouse Up...");
        down = false;
        var p = rect.attrs;
        var s = layer.getScale();
        console.log("Rect x: " + p.x + " y: " + p.y + " width: " + p.width + " height: " + p.height + " sx: " + s.x + " sy: " + s.y);
    });
}

var stageWidth = 1024;
var stageHeight = 700;
var imageWidth = 1299;
var imageHeight = 1064;

var initialScale = calcScale(imageWidth, imageHeight, stageWidth, stageHeight);

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "canvas",
    width: stageWidth,
    height: stageHeight
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    var diagram = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: -500,
        y: -500,
        image: imageObj,
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight
    });

    layer.add(diagram);
    layer.setScale(initialScale);

    whenAreaSelected(stage, layer, diagram);

    layer.draw();
}



var zoom = function (e) {
    var zoomAmount = e.wheelDeltaY * 0.001;
    layer.setScale(layer.getScale().x + zoomAmount)
    layer.draw();
}

document.addEventListener("mousewheel", zoom, false);

stage.add(layer);

imageObj.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/746967/Serenity/MARAYA%20GA.png';
```

It seems to me as though the mouseup event is intermittent at best.

Any idea what's going on here? It also seems to be worse when the Image is offset rather than displayed at 0,0. And I think it relates to the scaling of the layer as it all works okay at scale 1.

Is this a kinetic bug?

Answer (score 0):

**Try using layer.drawScene() instead of layer.draw() in your mousemove handler**

```
eventObj.on("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (!down) return;
    var relativePos = getRelativePos ( stage, layer );
    var p = rect.attrs;

    rect.setWidth(relativePos.x - p.x);
    rect.setHeight(relativePos.y - p.y);

    // try drawScene() instead of draw()

    layer.drawScene();
});
```

[Edited based on info forwarded by from user814628 here: Binding MouseMove event causes inconsistency with mouse release event being fired

Comment: Thanks for the info - I upgraded the fiddle to use KineticJS 4.4 but unfortunately it seems the same issue occurs: http://jsfiddle.net/tigz_uk/B8UDq/47/

Comment: Just received new info that might help you.  Try layer.drawScene in your mousemove event handler -- seems to fix the fiddle, anyway :D